# Bootstrap carousel with responsive HTML5 videos?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html5-video

I'm trying to make a carousel with videos. With the images it works fine the image are responsive even in mobile view. But with videos the width is responsive but not the height. Basically I would like to achieve the same comportement with a carousel image but with a video. I've tried many tricks online but none is doing it. My video is 1024/552px

Tried my best at a fiddle. You can see if you load the fiddle with a small width, it keeps the same height and it isn't responsive but the width of the carousel/video is (it crops the video on the sides though). It doesn't have the same comportement as an image. As you will see I have included an image in the second slide to further demonstrate my problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/687bsb21/1/

Here's the code :

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">            

        <div class="item active">
             <div align="center">
               <video autoplay loop>
                 <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" width="1024" height="552" type="video/mp4">
                 Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
          </div>
             <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>hello</h3>
              <p>hello</p>
            </div>
          </div> 
            <div class="item">
          <img src="http://dummyimage.com/1024x552/000/fff" class="img-responsive" alt="asfds">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>hello</h3>
              <p>hello.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carouselHelp" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carouselHelp" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
</div>
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add your css,

```
video{
width:100%
}
```

Comment: on the fiddle it works but on my project here's what it does : any idea why ? http://i.imgur.com/CcBBvBY.png

Comment: the video resizes now but the carousel does not? I removed all other css so the problem isn't there

Comment: I put this video{
max-width: 100%; height: auto;
} and now it works. Thanks for putting me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

also adding the width/height directly to the  tag works:

```
<video autoplay loop width="1024" height="552">
```

regards.

Comment: but this is not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution:

```
<div class="container">
  <video><source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
</div>

.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%
}
.container video{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);                            
}
```